# Dimension of the kernel of $T$ is $1$ .Yes/No

Tags: linear-algebra

let $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be  a nonzero linear  transformation such that $Tv=0$ for all  $v \in S  =\{(x,y,z) :x^2+y^2+z^2=1,x+y+z=0\}$.Then the dimension of the kernel of  $T$ has  to be

$a.0$

$b. 1$

$c. 2$

$d.0$ or $ 1$

**My attempt** : I think dim Ker $T=1$ because

$x^2+y^2+z^2-1=x+y+z =0$ can have  only one  solution

Take $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $z=0$

Comment: Not true. The intersection of a sphere with a plane through its center is a great circle.

Comment: That's not the only one solution of that system. $x=-\sqrt\frac{2}{3}$, $y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin So the kernel is the span of that great circle (which is the plane $x+y+z=0$ itself)...?

Comment: @Nothingspecial the kernel will be spanned by the vectors that are of unit length (so they lie on the circle, though the length restriction is redundant) and satisfy $x+y+z=0$. For example, a basis for the kernel could be $\left\{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0), \,\, (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\right\}$

Comment: @AnuragA I intended to mean the same. Effectively, $\text{ker } T=\{(x,y,z)\ : \ x+y+z=0 \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments the set $S$ is a circle of radius one centered at zero, therefore it contains two vectors that span a plane, so the kernel of $T$ have dimension at least two. However, as by assumption $T\neq 0$, then the kernel of $T$ has exactly dimension two.